# Stop the sorting and reposition the tr using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to Stop the sorting and reposition the tr using Javascript after clicking the cancel button in the modal.  But when I run the following code I am getting an error,

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'cancel'

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
 labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Do you really want to update the order?
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button id="cancel_update_order" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button id="update_order" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
new Tablesort(document.getElementById('table'));

var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
  var $originals = tr.children();
  var $helper = tr.clone();
  $helper.children().each(function(index) {
      $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
  });
  return $helper;
  }


  updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
    $('#exampleModal').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false
    })

    $('#update_order').on('click', function() {
      $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
          $(this).html(i + 1);
      });
      $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
    });

    $('#cancel_update_order').on('click', function() {
      $(this).sortable('cancel');
    });

  };

$("#table tbody").sortable({
  helper: fixHelperModified,
  stop: updateIndex
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Within `$('#cancel_update_order').on('click',` - `this` is the **button** - try `$("#table tbody").sortable("cancel")`

Comment: @freedomn-m I did not get you correctly.

Comment: You have this code: `$('#cancel_update_order').on('click', function() {
      $(this).sortable('cancel');
    });`  - within that code "this" refers to cancel_update_order, the button, *not* the table.

Comment: @freedomn-m it workes perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get this error:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'cancel'

it most likely means that you're calling "cancel" on a *different* element than the one sorting was initialised on.

In this case, you have this code:

```
$('#cancel_update_order').on('click', function() { 
    $(this).sortable('cancel'); 
});
```

within that code "this" refers to cancel_update_order, the button, not the table.

If you only have one sortable (that uses the outer method `updateIndex` then this is quickly fixed by referring to the table that had sortable initialised:

```
$('#cancel_update_order').on('click', function() { 
    $("#table tbody").sortable('cancel'); 
});
```

If you want this to be more reusable, then you'll need to keep a copy of "this" when it referred to the table:

```
updateIndex = function(e, ui) {

    var sortableElement = this;

    $('#cancel_update_order').on('click', function() {
      $(sortableElement).sortable('cancel');
    });

  };
```